# Happy Birthday, Stackoverflow. Free Beer!

Tags: discussion

The [first surviving question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/) was posted today, Jul 31 at 21:42 (GMT) or 2:42pm (Pacific Time).

[image]

Comment: I am punching you in the face *with my mind*.

Comment: What? free beer? where???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the **WORST** Friday Afternoon topic **EVER**.

Comment: Okay, then. Edit: "Happy Birthday, Free beer!"

Comment: I agree!  **BEST** ever!

Answer (score 4):

I expect my "Yearling" badge soon!

Comment: Why did you get a downvote?

Comment: Because it's community wiki and they don't cost anything to cast.

Comment: *shrugs and down-votes TheTXI*

Comment: *looks around for something of Shog's to vote down*

Comment: I'm getting pretty pissed of at people that *always* ask for the why of a downvote...

Comment: Well, you are costing them rep, they want to know what they did wrong.

Comment: I'm getting pretty pissed off at people that *always* get pretty pissed off at people that *always* ask for the why of a downvote.

Comment: (Normally it costs them rep)

Comment: @ThosePeople: Stop the whining already

Comment: I hate people who use **italics** for emphasis.

Comment: I was just curious why somebody would downvote Greg's innocuous answer...

Comment: I'm getting pretty pissed off at TheTXI... (nah, you're ok)

Comment: I'm getting pretty pissed later tonight from all of the free birthday beer!!

Comment: I don't use *italics*, I use the '*' (star) symbol and it happens to render as **italics text**... nothing I can do

Comment: I hate people who call *bold* **italics**.

Comment: Actually , you can \*escape\* the asterisks!!

Comment: But I don't know *how*

Comment: Just use a `\\` character before the `*` character.

Comment: \*Cool!\*           .

Comment: I'm getting pissed off, about how I'm not pissed off, about any of this.

Comment: @jjnguy You can also escape a single backslash in code: ``\`` (`\`\`\\`\``) `;)`

Comment: And please don't ask me how I escaped the escaped single backslash.